# Ng-Grid will collapse rows after data refresh, how to prevent that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using Ng-Grid with grouping option, where groups are collapsed by default. 
Each row of data has a link to perform some operation on it. After operation is done, grid should refresh data. This part works fine.

The problem is with aggregation: after data refresh, all rows get collapsed. This is really annoying.

Is there any possibility to expand specific group after data refresh?
I tried:

```
$scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.rowFactory.aggCache[$scope.expandedGroupID].toggleExpand();
```

and

```
$scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.rowFactory.aggCache[$scope.expandedGroupID].collapsed=false;
```

But that didn't work.

Example Plunker with grid configuuration can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wtoCSA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone struggles with the same problem, here is how I fixed that:

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventData', function () {
    $scope.availableGroupsOptions.ngGrid.rowFactory.aggCache[idx].toggleExpand();      
});
```

The key is 'ngGridEventData'.

Answer (score 0):

Or go to the ng-grid.js and make *groupsCollapsedByDefault* to false.

So if you refresh the grid in that case the grid status will remains the same (collapsed grid will be collapsed and expanded grid will remain expanded.)

Thank you. I hope this helps, Chess !!